# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Mixed port numbers after enabling console login authentication?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security, worklight-console

Wishing to have a Worklight Console Authentication I followed the infocenter instructions from this link at [infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_protecting_ibm_worklight_console.html?resultof=%22protecting%22%20%22protect%22%20%22console%22%20%22consol%22%20).It seems to be working at the first glance as entering the console it prompts the login form.

Going to the console URL at `http://192.168.168.154:9080/finance/console/#catalog` it brings the login page right away. So far so good.

After entering the right username/password (both defined at worklight.properties) the login page redirects to the Worklight console at port 10080 and fails to load the page

**Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.168.154:10080.**

As you can read it tries to connect to `http://192.168.168.154:10080/finance/console`. It should not happen I guess, as port 10080 was not configured.

I have no idea why it is redirecting to this port. I searched inside the config files for 10080 and could not find any reference to it. I think somehow WL is getting this 10080 as a default as it is the port used for development.

Here is the files snippets I am using to enable Login Console:

**worklight.properties:**

```
#publicWorkLightHostname=localhost
# http or https
#publicWorkLightProtocol=http
# For default port leave empty
#publicWorkLightPort=10080  <-- it is commented out

console.username=finance
console.password=finance
```

**authenticationConfig.xml**

```
 <staticResources>
    <resource id="worklightConsole" securityTest="WorklightConsole">
            <urlPatterns>/console*</urlPatterns>
    </resource> 
    ....
</staticResources>

 <securityTests>

        <customSecurityTest name="WorklightConsole">
            <test realm="WorklightConsole" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
  ...
</securityTests>
```

**server.xml**

```
   <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" >
        <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>
    </httpEndpoint>
    <!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the IBM Worklight Console. -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/publicWorkLightProtocol" value='"http"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/publicWorkLightPort" value='"9080"'/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/serverSessionTimeout" value='"10"'/>
```

Any idea on how to solve this port mismatch issue ? Env is WL 6.0 on Liberty

P.S: Later on we plan to user LDAP instead. For now, having the username/passaword in the properties would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `worklight.properties`, uncomment the `#publicWorkLightPort=10080` property and change it to `9080`.

worklight.properties is part of the Worklight project's .war file that is deployed into the application server; the application server may have its own port number set in server.xml, but the .war (project) has some specific properties of its own.

During my testing I encountered the same issue, but once uncommenting and changing the port value in worklight.properties, the re-direct then worked properly after logging-in.

Comment: ok, I ll give it try. The worlight.properties has a comment that confused me. It is: #   In production mode, these properites are mandatory - must be overrided by jndi entries
Which is mandatory ? The ones in the properties or the jndi ones ?