# IBM Worklight - Application Center Console - Redirection to port 9080

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

We are trying to setup the Worklight Server for production, which is behind a reverse proxy that will help manage the SSL certificate.

What this means is that, when the user hit the domain, say `https://mydomain.com:443`, the proxy will automatically forward the request to the Worklight Server on port 9080.

After the setup is done for the reverse proxy following [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/c_ac_ssl_config.html) guide, the `installers.html` page is working well. However we notice that when we try to access the console using `https://mydomain.com:443/appcenterconsole`, the user gets redirect to `http://mydomain.com:9080/appcenterconsole/console.html` instead and this is causing problem.

I searched around and found this link [Worklight Console redirects to port 9080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042209/worklight-console-redirects-to-port-9080), which is similar to the problem i'm having. **Is there a way for me to configure the Websphere Liberty Profile so that it will use the reverse proxy URL as the redirection URL?**

I notice also that the `index.html` file in the `appcenterconsole.war` is using the meta refresh method to do the redirection. I'm tempted to change it to use a full URL, but then i also notice that the same issue happens when we go to the `login.html` and perform login. (Whereby after login, the page redirects the user with the 9080 port as well).

Any pointers or idea are welcomes. The Worklight version used is 6.1.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

The network setup in my environment:

Proxy Gateway (with SSL cert) configured to connect to Worklight Server for port 9080 whenever a connection with port 80 or 443 is received. Therefore:

`https://mydomain.com:443/appcenterconsole` -> will be mapped to `http://worklightserver:9080/appcenterconsole`

The mapping is done internally between the proxy and the worklight server.

When we type the full URL on the browser, ie. `https://mydomain.com:443/appcenterconsole/console.html` after i login, the console works fine.

Comment: Please do not confuse worklight console with application center - these are 2 separate entities.

Comment: Yes i understand, but the problem is similar. Is there a way to configure this? Thanks.

Comment: What proxy do you use? It seems a problem in the proxy configuration. The proxy should masquerade the incoming request so that it can translate outgoing responses. The translation of outgoing responses seems to work for the IP address itself but not for the port. That is, the response reaches the browser with a wrong port in the header, hence the browser redirects wrongly. It is the responsibility of the reverse proxy to ensure the IP and port translation.

Comment: The proxy settings seems fine as we are able to access the service via the mobile client, and download apps normally. From my observation, it is when the console tries to perform redirection (i.e. after login, redirect you to the main app page) that is giving problem.

Comment: Tests made with Liberty Profile 8551 and IBM HTTP Server 855 don't show this problem. Entering https://domain:443/appcenterconsole redirects correctly to https://domain:9443/appcenterconsole/login.html. Be sure that the proxy doesn't redirect to the http protocol. By default for example with IHS, the transport between IHS and the application server is HTTP and not HTTPS

Comment: what we neeeded is that it stays with the public domain, i.e. in your example, it will be to stay at domain:443/appcenterconsole rather than be redirected to domain:9443/appcenterconsole. This is because the SSL layer is handled by the proxy server, and there's no SSL cert configured for the worklight server.

Comment: @GeorgSander your points seems valid, unfortunately i'm not that experienced with network configuration, could you elaborate a bit on what is the translation means? thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me from where did u download Tandem appcenterconsole.war file , I am not able to find cource

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up the JNDI entries detailed here?

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fappcenter%2Fr_ac_appres_endpoint.html

Comment: ya i did setup the JNDI entries there, the application center RESTful service is working well, just that when it tries to do the normal redirection (i.e. after login, redirect you to the main app page) it will give problem

Comment: Could yo please tell me from where we can get applcationcenter.war file . I amn not able to find. Thanks