# Open Worklight Console using https and secure port on Worklight development

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm facing an issue where I need to open my Worklight development console using secure port so I can also open analytic server using secure port too.

I tried to find my answer in this:

[IBM Worklight 6.0 - Mixed port numbers after enabling console login authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124666/ibm-worklight-6-0-mixed-port-numbers-after-enabling-console-login-authenticati)

But wasn't successful:

My server.xml is:

```
<server description="worklight">

       <featureManager>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>

<!--
        <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
        <feature>ldapRegistry-3.0</feature>
-->
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <webContainer invokeFlushAfterService="false"/>
    <webContainer com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressLoggingServiceRuntimeExcep="true"/>
    <webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>

    <!-- non standard ports were used to avoid future collision with other WebSphere products. -->
    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="10080" httpsPort="10443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint">
    <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>

    </httpEndpoint>

<!--  change Worklight server side logging: 
      change consoleLogLevel to INFO to see Worklight JavaScript Logger API output
      (for example: in Worklight Adapters).
-->
    <logging consoleLogLevel="AUDIT" copySystemStreams="false"/>

    <!-- enable next element for Worklight Server traces. 
         change traceSpecification to enable fine grain printing to trace.log file. 
    <logging traceSpecification="com.worklight.*=debug=enabled"/>
    -->

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

    <!--
        Thread pool
    -->
    <executor coreThreads="200" id="default" keepAlive="60s" maxThreads="400" name="LargeThreadPool" rejectedWorkPolicy="CALLER_RUNS" stealPolicy="STRICT"/>

    <administrator-role>
       <user>admin</user>
    </administrator-role>
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="worklight"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host" value="localhost"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port" value="10443"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.platform" value="Liberty"/>
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.clustermode" value="Standalone"/>


<!--
    Worklight Console settings START ...
-->
    <basicRegistry id="worklight" realm="worklightRealm">
        <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
        <user name="monitor" password="demo"/>
        <user name="deployer" password="demo"/>
        <user name="operator" password="demo"/>
        <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
    </basicRegistry>
<!--
    JMX admin user JNDI entries
-->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.user" value="admin"/>

    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.pwd" value="admin"/>
<!--
    Disabling security integration
-->
    <httpSession securityIntegrationEnabled="false"/>
<!--
    Declare the IBM Worklight Admin Services application.
-->
    <application context-root="worklightadmin" id="worklight-management-service" location="worklight-management-service.war" name="WorklightServices" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="worklightadmin">
                <user name="admin"/>
            </security-role>
                <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
                <user name="deployer"/>
            </security-role>
                <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
                <user name="monitor"/>
            </security-role>
                <security-role name="worklightoperator">
                <user name="operator"/>
            </security-role>
        </application-bnd>
        <classloader delegation="parentLast">
            <privateLibrary>
                <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil*.jar"/>
            </privateLibrary>
        </classloader>
    </application>
<!--
    Declare the IBM Worklight Admin Console application.
-->
    <application context-root="worklightconsole" id="worklight-management-ui" location="worklight-management-ui.war" name="WorklightConsole" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="worklightadmin">
                <user name="admin"/>
            </security-role>
                <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
                <user name="deployer"/>
            </security-role>
                <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
                <user name="monitor"/>
            </security-role>
                <security-role name="worklightoperator">
                <user name="operator"/>
            </security-role>
        </application-bnd>
    </application>

    <library id="DerbyLib">
        <fileset dir="${wlp.user.dir}/shared/resources/derby" includes="derby.jar"/>
    </library>
<!--
    Declare the IBM Worklight Console admin database.
-->
    <dataSource jndiName="worklightadmin/jdbc/WorklightAdminDS" transactional="false">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DerbyLib"/>
        <properties.derby.embedded createDatabase="create" databaseName="${wlp.user.dir}/shared/resources/derbyDB/WLADMIN" user="WLADMINISTRATOR"/>
    </dataSource>
<!--
    ... Worklight Console settings END
-->

    <application id="_MobileBrowserSimulator" location="_MobileBrowserSimulator.war" name="_MobileBrowserSimulator" type="war"/>

    <application context-root="/_analytics" id="_analytics" location="_analytics.war" name="_analytics" type="war">
        <classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
    </application>





    <library id="worklight-6.2.0">
        <fileset dir="${wlp.user.dir}/shared/resources" includes="worklight-jee-library-6.2.0.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil*.jar"/>
    </library>





    <application context-root="/MobileGRS" id="MobileGRS" location="MobileGRS.war" name="MobileGRS" type="war">
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="worklight-6.2.0">
            <privateLibrary>
                <fileset dir="${wlp.user.dir}/shared/resources" includes="org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.2.5.jar"/>
            </privateLibrary>
        </classloader>
    </application>

    <jndiEntry jndiName="MobileGRS/wl.analytics.queue.size" value="1"/>

    <jndiEntry jndiName="MobileGRS/wl.analytics.url" value="http://localhost:10080/_analytics/data"/>
</server>
```

worklight.properties:

```
# HTTP or HTTPS
publicWorkLightProtocol=https
# For default port leave empty
publicWorkLightPort=10443
```

When I click on open worklight console from eclipse, it is opening port 10080:

http://192.168.0.102:10080/worklightconsole/index.html#

If I changed the port to 10443, I can't connect.

Am I missing something.

WL version 6.2.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in your server.xml, you did not change the Analytics URL to be HTTPS and 10443...

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="MobileGRS/wl.analytics.url" value="http://localhost:10080/_analytics/data"/>
```

After that, accessing the console at https://localhost:10443/worklightconsole worked, as well as https://localhost:10443/_analytics/console.

The above URLs were of course prompted as unsafe because I did not add a valid SSL certificate to the server.

Note that the Analytics console URL in the Worklight Console still uses HTTP. You'll need to manually change that to HTTPS (couldn't find where to change that).

Comment: I made the change on analytics jndi value and when I deploy my adapter it is still showing 10080:                                                                      [2015-08-21 12:36:41]             Starting build of adapter: image 
[2015-08-21 12:36:41]             Deploying adapter: image 
[2015-08-21 12:36:41]             Server host: 192.168.0.102 
[2015-08-21 12:36:41]             Server port: 10080 
[2015-08-21 12:36:47]             Adapter build and deploy finished.